# Is it possible to override the error message that Django shows for UniqueConstraint error? (IntegrityError)

Tags: django, unique-constraint

Using UniqueConstraint on multiple fields and it is working properly, but I want to override the error message.

Have gone through many postings, some of them quite dated, and none seem to specify how to override this particular instance. (IntegrityError)

Fields are User and Skill Group. I would like error message to simply say "Skill Group already in use." It currently reads "Skill group with this User and Skill group already exists." Thanks.

**Updated:**
Thought I should post related code:

```
models.py
class SkillGroup(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill_group = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    sequence = models.IntegerField(default=999)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'skill_group'], name='unique_skillgroup'),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.skill_group

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('skillgroup-list')

forms.py
class SkillGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SkillGroup
        fields = ('user', 'skill_group')
        widgets = {
            'user': forms.HiddenInput,
        }

views.py
class SkillGroupCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = SkillGroup
    form_class = SkillGroupForm

    def get_initial(self):
        return {'user': self.request.user}

    def form_valid(self, form):
        try:
            result = super().form_valid(form)
        except IntegrityError as err:
            if str(err) == "Skill group with this User and Skill group already exists.":
                raise IntegrityError("Skill Group already in use.")
            raise
        else:
            return result
```

```
IntegrityError at /skillgroup/create/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_skillgroup"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, skill_group)=(1, Quality Assurance) already exists.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/skillgroup/create/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_skillgroup"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, skill_group)=(1, Quality Assurance) already exists.
Exception Location: C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute, line 84
Python Executable:  C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Christopher George\\bcs\\basicrecruiter',
 'C:\\Users\\CHRIST~1\\Envs\\bcs\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\CHRIST~1\\Envs\\bcs\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\CHRIST~1\\Envs\\bcs\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\CHRIST~1\\Envs\\bcs\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\christopher '
 'george\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\christopher '
 'george\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\CHRIST~1\\Envs\\bcs',
 'C:\\Users\\CHRIST~1\\Envs\\bcs\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 18 Apr 2019 02:53:51 +0000
```

```
Traceback:
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/skillgroup/create/

Django Version: 2.2
Python Version: 3.7.2
Installed Applications:
['recruiter.apps.RecruiterConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'phone_field',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_skillgroup"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, skill_group)=(1, Quality Assurance) already exists.
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py" in dispatch
  52.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  172.         return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "C:\Users\Christopher George\bcs\basicrecruiter\recruiter\views.py" in form_valid
  104.         return super().form_valid(form)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in form_valid
  125.         self.object = form.save()

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save
  458.             self.instance.save()

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  741.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  779.                 force_update, using, update_fields,

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  870.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  908.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1186.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1332.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  99.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  67.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  76.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\Envs\bcs\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /skillgroup/create/
Exception Value: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_skillgroup"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, skill_group)=(1, Quality Assurance) already exists.
```

**Update 2:**
 Based on some reading in the Django documentation, I tried changing it to with no success:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
      result = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    except IntegrityError as err:
      if str(err) == "Skill group with this User and Skill group already exists.":
        raise IntegrityError("Skill Group already in use.")
      raise
    else:
      return result
```

Comment: Please pay special attention to the "Minimal" section here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 10):

By default, before Django 4.1, there is no default way to customize the error message.
Django 4.1 now includes a `violation_error_message` attribute that customizes the error message.

> BaseConstraint.violation_error_message
> The error message used when ValidationError is raised during model validation.
> Defaults to "Constraint “%(name)s” is violated."
> [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/#violation-error-message)

For your case using Django =>4.1

```
class Meta:
       constraints = [
           models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'skill_group'], name='unique_skillgroup', violation_error_message='your_error_message'),
]
```

Comment: This is the best solution for those using Django 4.1. The one downside is that if you want to change the error message, you will have to re-apply migrations.

Comment: [According to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/#id1), «This message is not used for UniqueConstraints with fields and without a condition. Such UniqueConstraints show the same message as constraints defined with Field.unique or in Meta.unique_together.»

Comment: How do you show this violation error message in your template file?

Answer (score 2):

You could catch the exception and re-raise it with your custom message:

```
try:
    # This is the statement that raises the exception
except IntegrityError as err:
    if str(err) == "Skill group with this User and Skill group already exists.":
        raise IntegrityError("Skill Group already in use.")
    # Propagate the exception if the condition is not matched.
    raise
```

---

#### Update

`CreateView` inherits (among others) form `ModelFormMixin` which has a method that, according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin):

> **form_valid(form)**
>
> Saves the form instance, sets the current object for the view, and redirects to get_success_url().

So you could:

```
class YourView(CreateView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        try:
            result = super().form_valid(form)
        except IntegrityError as err:
            if str(err) == "Skill group with this User and Skill group already exists.":
                raise IntegrityError("Skill Group already in use.")
            # Propagate exception is candition is not matched.
            raise
         else:
            return result
```

---

### Update 2

Perhaps you could instead put that code in your form's save method.

```
class SkillGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # ...

    def save(**kwargs):
        try:
            result = super().save(**kwargs)
        except IntegrityError as err:
            if str(err) == "Skill group with this User and Skill group already exists.":
                raise IntegrityError("Skill Group already in use.")
            raise
        else:
            return result
```

---

### Update 3: Answering @Hamidreza's comment:

> This will raise the original error anyway! cause you are raising another error, right inside the exception handling section! So it will show the original error AND the overrode one! saying "during handling of the above exception, another exception occurred"

Of course if you look at the stack trace you will see both exceptions as you  pointed out. BUT ...   this only will happen if you do not handle the exception.

The point here is that the OP wants to change the error message that it's propagated and for that purpose, the solution is good enough. For instance:

```
def foo(): 
   try: 
       1 / 0 
   except ZeroDivisionError: 
       raise ZeroDivisionError("My very own error message")

try: 
   foo() 
except ZeroDivisionError as err: 
   print(err)  # Prints: "My very own error message"
```

So:

```
try:
   form.valid_form()
except IntegrityError as err:
   # Here err will contains the error the OP wants if it is the case.
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but where do I put this code? Also, should it be SkillGroup.save()? Thank you.

Comment: You should put this code around the statement that rise the target excepion.

Comment: I assumed the exception is risen when the app tries to write the data to the DB. (Postgres) I am using a generic class-based CreateView so I am not exactly sure where the exception is specifically raised. Thanks.

Comment: Modified, but still getting default message. I tried removing the If clause in the event the text was not an exact match and still got default message. Also added from django.db import IntegrityError at top of views.py.

Comment: I have posted related above.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace of such exception? I needed to recommend a more accurate place to put that code. Perhaps you need to put that code in the save method of the form

Comment: I tried adding it with no change. How would I get a "stack trace"? Should I make it so the system errors out instead of handling it with current message? Thanks again!!

Comment: Yes, copy the system error an paste it in your question, please.

Comment: Copied. Tried changing to see if err == 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_skillgroup"' and the longer text beginning with that. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Ok, by your stack trace I can see the lowest point where you can put this code is in the model save method. Just copy and paste the method `save` from the answer's Update 2 to your model.

Comment: I had tried something similar earlier without luck. I just moved the def save() to the model and still no change. I really appreciate the effort. I do not understand why this is so elusive.

Comment: Based on some reading in the Django documentation, I tried changing it to with no success:
```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            result = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        except IntegrityError as err:
            if str(err) == "Skill group with this User and Skill group already exists.":
                raise IntegrityError("Skill Group already in use.")
            raise
        else:
            return result
```

Comment: This will raise the original error anyway! cause you are raising another error, right inside the exception handling section! So it will show the original error AND the overrode one! saying "during handling of the above exception, another exception occurred"

Comment: @Hamidreza I've updated the answer with a section related to your comment.